# Requisição com Volley o Webservice não reconhece json

Tags: php, java, android, ios

Estou tentando fazer uma requisição POST com o Volley Android, mas o meu Webservice não reconhece o arquivo json que é enviado como parâmetro. Com o plugin Postman do Google Chrome o Webservice consome perfeitamente sem problemas.

Abaixo está meu método que consume o json no Webservice:

```
@POST
@Path("/login")
@Consumes("application/json")
@Produces("application/json")
public Response authenticate(Usuario usuario) {

    try{

        System.out.println("CPF: " + usuario.getCpfUsuario());

        return Response.ok("OK").build();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        return Response.status(Response.Status.UNAUTHORIZED).build();
    }    

}
```

Meu cliente Android:

```
Usuario u = new Usuario("sadsadsad","asdaddad");
Gson gson = new Gson();

String s =  new String(gson.toJson(u));
Map<String, String> params  = new HashMap<String, String>();
params.put("Usuario", s);

JsonObjectRequest mCustomRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(
            Request.Method.POST,
            "http://(meuip):8080/webservice/authentication/login",
            new JSONObject(params),
            new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                    mTextView.setText("Retorno: " + response);
                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener(){
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    mTextView.setText("Falhou: " + error);
                    Log.i("SAIDA: ", "" + error);
                }
            }){

        @Override
        public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
            HashMap<String, String> headers = new HashMap<String, String>();
            headers.put("Accept", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
            return headers;
        }

    };

    NetworkConnection.getInstance(getActivity()).addRequestQueue(mCustomRequest);
```

A saída no Webservice quando acessado com o cliente Android é CPF: null e com o Postman CPF: "o valor passado"

A resposta do cliente android é: com.android.volley.AuthFailureError

Comment: No Postman, voce coloca os parametros como um JSON? Ocorre algum erro no servidor?

Comment: Um exemplo de como passo o parametro no Postman: {"ativoUsuario":false,"cpfUsuario”:"11111111111","idDeptoUsuario":0,"numeroUsuario":0,"senhaUsuario":"5efe56928251a83b29af558c258e0c50"}

Comment: Se você passa no Postman um JSON, compare se há diferença entre ele e o que é gerado pelo Android!

Comment: Gera exatamente igual.

Comment: Tente passar desta forma:  new JSONObject("{\"ativoUsuario\":false,\"cpfUsuario”:\"11111111111\",\"idDeptoUsuario\":0,\"numeroUsuar\u200C​io\":0,\"senhaUsuario\":\"5efe56928251a83b29af558c258e0c50\"} ")

Comment: Copiei igual me passou da problema de indentação... Alguma sugestão ?

Comment: Veja este post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23220695/google-volley-how-to-send-a-post-request-with-json-data

Comment: Então fiz igual o exemplo desse link e acontece a mesma coisa, creio que o json que está chegando no webservice não seja compatível.

Comment: #Thiago Luiz Domacoski, abaixo implementei a solução. Eu estava transformando o Objeto em uma String.

Answer (score 1):

No exemplo acima apenas foi necessário comentar as linhas:

```
Usuario u = new Usuario("sadsadsad","asdaddad");
Gson gson = new Gson();

String s =  new String(gson.toJson(u));
```

Em seguida passar os parâmetros corretamente:

```
Map<String, String> params  = new HashMap<String, String>();
params.put("cpfUsuario", "11111111111");
params.put("senhaUsuario", "blablabla");
```

Comment: Parabéns cara !